# Error: Unexpected $this in PHP Code

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have two PHP scripts, `dispatcher.php` and `processor.php` (there are more, but I've commented the others out because they're not necessary at the moment).

I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in /----home directory-----/classes/processor.php on line 12

Here's the code for processor.php:

```
class Processor{

    protected $player;
    protected $name;
    protected $id;

    function __construct(){
    }

    function loadvars($request){
        $this->loadvar($this->name, $request, "name");
    }

    private function loadvar($target, $request, $name){
        if(isset($request[$name])){
            $target = $request[$name];
        }
        else{
            $target = "";
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code for dispatcher.php:

```
require('classes/processor.php');

$test = new Processor();
$test->loadvars($_GET);
```

I don't see why this error occurs?

I'm coding using Sublime on Windows, if that matters.

Comment: working perfectly for me

Comment: Have you tried storing `$this->name` in a local variable and then using that local variable as argument?

Comment: Fixed it -> I think some weird unicode character got into the file. Copied and pasted code from here when MyWay said it was working, and now it works. Weird!

Comment: Try initializing the variable `$this->name` into the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it!

**Try retyping the file if you have weird parse errors.** I copied the code back from StackOverflow (where I typed it above) and it worked. Guess some unparseable character got into the file somewhere.

Comment: That can possible be the problem, but in the code posted here there is nothing wrong. Use a hex view to see these characters. I think there should be a plugin for sublime.

Comment: Yeah - it was the issue - I've been copying it into notepad and notice little byte blocks that don't show up otherwise.